# UILabel Adjust Font to Fit text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm getting an error for this code

```
cell.label.numberOfLines = 2
cell.label.text = adjust1
cell.label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12.0)
cell.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth
```

The Error is  at this line

```
cell.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth
```

The Error is

```
The Expression resolves to an unused I-value
```

Need a fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
cell.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth
```

with this:

```
cell.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: No problem, accept the answer if it solved your problem.